# Switching hide and show in html form

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wanted to show and hide the visibility of the html form. I have 2 modes when mode 1 is selected then the form should show up with the text box and when mode 2 is selected the form with radio buttons should show up and mode 1 should be hidden and initially everything is hidden. This is what I have done so far but my css with jQuery is not able to apply.

HTML Form

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Lets switch</legend>
     Mode 1 
    <input type="radio" class="modeClass" name="change_mode" value="Text box">
     Mode 2  
    <input type="radio" class="modeClass" name="change_mode" value="Radio buttons"> <br>
    <div id= "text_form">
   <label class="hidden"> Name:</label> <input type="text" class ="hidden"><br>
   <label class= "hidden"> Email:</label> <input type="text" class ="hidden"><br>
    <label class= "hidden"> Date of birth:</label> <input type="text" class ="hidden">
    </div>
   <div id="radio_form">
   <input type="radio" name="sex" class ="hidden" value="male"><label  class="hidden">Male</label>
   <input type="radio" name="sex" class="hidden" value="female"><label class= "hidden">Female</label>
   </form>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

CSS

```
<style>
.hidden 
{

  display:none;

} 
</style>
```

JQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    /*Getting the value of the checked radio buttons*/
    $("input:radio[class=modeClass]").click(function() {
       var value = $(this).val();
     /*  console.log(value);*/
    if(value=="Text box")
    {

    $("#text_form").css("display","block");
   /* console.log("Time to call input box");*/
    }

    if(value=="Radio buttons")
    {

    $("#radio_form").css("display","block");

    }


    });

    });
```

Any idea suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: For that html `"input.modeClass"` would be an easier way to select the radios than `"input:radio[class=modeClass]"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to apply `class="hidden"` to so many elements. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Hu9Ka/) is a fiddle with working code.

### HTML

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Lets switch</legend>Mode 1
        <input type="radio" class="modeClass" name="change_mode" value="Text box" />Mode 2
        <input type="radio" class="modeClass" name="change_mode" value="Radio buttons" />
        <br />
        <div id="text_form" class="hidden">
            <label>Name:</label>
            <input type="text" />
            <br />
            <label>Email:</label>
            <input type="text" />
            <br />
            <label>Date of birth:</label>
            <input type="text" />
        </div>
        <div id="radio_form" class="hidden">
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" />
            <label>Male</label>
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" />
            <label>Female</label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    /*Getting the value of the checked radio buttons*/
    $("input.modeClass").on( 'click', function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (value == "Text box") {
            $("#text_form").show();
            $("#radio_form").hide();
        }
        if (value == "Radio buttons") {
            $("#text_form").hide();
            $("#radio_form").show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you very much for clearly explaining and works the way that I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this

http://jsfiddle.net/pramodsankar007/u9RZy/

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Lets switch</legend>Mode 1
        <input type="radio" class="modeClass" name="change_mode" value="Text box">Mode 2
        <input type="radio" class="modeClass" name="change_mode" value="Radio buttons">
        <br>
        <div id="text_form" class="hidden">
            <label>Name:</label>
            <input type="text">
            <br>
            <label>Email:</label>
            <input type="text">
            <br>
            <label>Date of birth:</label>
            <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div id="radio_form" class="hidden">
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">
            <label>Male</label>
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">
            <label>Female</label>
</form>
</fieldset>
</form>





$("input:radio[class=modeClass]").click(function () {
      var value = $(this).val();
      if (value == "Text box") {
          $("#radio_form").show();
          $("#text_form").hide();
          /* console.log("Time to call input box");*/
      }
      if (value == "Radio buttons") {
         $("#radio_form").hide();
          $("#text_form").show();

      }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your jquery seems quite ok but you need little bit extra:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input:radio[class=modeClass]").click(function() {
       var value = $(this).val();
       if(value=="Text box"){
           $("#text_form").show().siblings("#radio_form").hide();
       }

       if(value=="Radio buttons"){
           $("#radio_form").show().siblings("#text_form").hide();
       }
    });
});
```

#### [FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/dqhZC/)

Answer (score 0):

Jquery ha s hide and show method.

```
$("#text_form).hide();
```

There is also toggle, which helps if you don't know whether is is currently shown or not.

http://api.jquery.com/hide/

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 0):

I am not a big fan of `.show()`/`.hide()` as it causes other inconsistencies. I created a live JSFiddle with a slightly improved version of your code. Just as Dream Eater did, I consolidated all your `class='hidden'` statements onto the parent `div` element, making it cleaner and much easier to work with. Additionally, you did not need the `.css('display', 'block')` method, so that was removed. Other than that, the code was fine and here is what you were looking for:

link--> **http://jsfiddle.net/CFP9N/**